# move files from a list of files

Tags: batch, rsync

So, I have a list of files in a text file. I believe it's about 100,000 files.

The files in said list are spread across many directories, have different sizes, filenames, extensions, ages, etc.

I am trying to find a way to move those files, and just those, to another drive.

Complicating factor: some of the files have the same name, but are not the same file. They can't just be moved into one folder with an overwriting or ignoring policy towards multiples.

Preferably, I would like them to retain their directory structure, but only have the files that I want inside the destination directory. (the destination drive isn't big enough to simply copy everything).

Below is an example of some lines in the file:

```
    media/dave/xdd/cruzer/F#(NTFS 1)/Raw Files/Portable Network Graphic file/3601-3900/FILE3776.PNG/Windows/winsxs/amd64_microsoft-windows-o..disc-style-memories_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_51190840a935f980/Title_mainImage-mask.png
```

media/dave/xdd/d1/other/hd1/Program Files/DVD Maker/Shared/DvdStyles/Memories/Title_content-background.png

I have tried to use

```
    rsync -a --files-from=/sourcefile.txt / /media/destinationhdd
```

However, this just tries to copy my root directory to the destination. Please help, how to I just copy the accursed files that I want to?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming a Unix-like environment, so I'll write this in bash script, but the concept is more or less the same across similar scripting languages...

Run this script in the directory that the files in the file list are relative to...

```
#!/bin/sh

# (naive) File migration script

IFS=$'\n'
destination_path = "/path/to/destination/here/"

for file in `cat filelist.txt`
do
    cp -v --parents $file $destination_path
done
```

What this accomplishes is that you are preserving the source parent directory structure when copying to the specified destination. rsync is great for backing up whole swathes of files that you regularly update as thats what the algorithm is tuned for. But for simpler operations, the base Unix commands wrapped in a simple script are more than adequate. Note that this also sets the `IFS` bash variable that is ordinarily comprised of `<space><tab><newline>` although the setting probably won't be preserved upon script exit.